# Replace with regex/wildcard

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I use a console app to migrate thousand of pages form one environment to another

I am updating all links in the HTML to reflect the new site hierarchy which works fine but I guess it's possible to improve performance a bit

URL for old links looks something like:

href="me.get?site.sectionshow&Page300"

and in the new environment it will be something like

href="http://siteA/pages/page300.aspx"

I have this loop to replace URLs:

string updatedContent = content;

```
for (int i = 1; i < 600; i++)
{
    // these are for links to other pages
    updatedContent = updatedContent.Replace("href=\"me.get?site.sectionshow&PAGE" + i.ToString("D3"),
        applicationSite + "/pages/page" + i.ToString("D3") + ".aspx");

    updatedContent = updatedContent.Replace("href=\"me.get?site.sectionshow&Page" + i.ToString("D3"),
        applicationSite + "/pages/page" + i.ToString("D3") + ".aspx");

    updatedContent = updatedContent.Replace("href=\"me.get?site.sectionshow&page" + i.ToString("D3"),
        applicationSite + "/pages/page" + i.ToString("D3") + ".aspx");
}

return updatedContent;
```

Sometimes sectionshow is all lowercase, sometimes uppercase, sometimes mixed, same with Page/page/PAGE

is there a neat way to use regex or similar to not have these multiple statements in the loop? I can make all links lowercase but not the rest of the HTML content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
{
    const string original = "href=\"me.get?site.sectionshow&page;"
    const string replace = "/pages/page";
    Regex reg = new Regex(original + i.ToString("D3"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    reg.Replace(updatedContent, replace + i.ToString("D3") + ".aspx")
}
```